# R data clustering using a pre-defined distance/similarity matrix

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, similarity, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

I developed a new document similarity measure (A method which calculate the amount of similarity/distance between two documents). I'm going to know how well this measure?

**Clustering** is an application which is based on a distance/similarity measure. So, I decided to evaluate the effectiveness of the proposed measure in different data clustering algorithms.

I read about [different clustering algorithms in R](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cluster.html). Suppose I have a document collection **D** which contains **n** documents, organized in **k** clusters. I want to evaluate the application of my similarity/distance measure in a variety of clustering algorithms (partitional, hierarchical and topic-based). The problem is that all examples and tutorials start from a "**data**" matrix, but I have a **distance/similarity** matrix.

Would you please help me with some hints in R?

Comment: Is that so? Following your link, under *Hierarchical Agglomerative* the analysis e.g. starts with (building) a distance matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hclust()` requires a dissimilarity structure that is a `dist` object.  If you start with a numeric matrix, `m`, you can create a `dist` object like so:

```
d <- as.dist(m)
```

You can then perform hierarchical clustering using `hclust()` like so:

```
hclust(d)
```